# Where is translation for XML configurations is happening in the code?

Tags: code, localisation

In XML files (such as `system.xml`) I can specify a `translate` attribute for nodes to be translated. Where is this translation taking place in the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no central place for all configuration structures. For tabs for example it happens in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Tabs::initTabs()`:

```
$helperName = $configFields->getAttributeModule($tab);
$label = Mage::helper($helperName)->__((string)$tab->label);
```

Comment: Mark ot as answer please :-)